# Syslog full of "CIFS VFS: BAD_NETWORK_NAME" errors

Tags: samba, network-share

I've recently move a mounted (windows) share in the fstab config from:

```
//[old server]/[share] /mnt/[share] cifs credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,x-systemd.automount,uid=112,gid=116  0  0
```

to

```
//[new server]/[share] /mnt/[share] cifs credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,x-systemd.automount,uid=112,gid=116  0  0
```

i.e. exactly the same config, but on a different remote server. The mount is all working fine, no problems, but the syslog is full of:

```
Jul 31 13:36:43 [hostname] kernel: CIFS VFS: BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \\[old server]\[share]
Jul 31 13:36:45 [hostname] kernel: CIFS VFS: BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \\[old server]\[share]
Jul 31 13:36:47 [hostname] kernel: CIFS VFS: BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \\[old server]\[share]
```

So the old server share details (now unavailable) are cached somewhere, but I can't figure out where that would be. Does anyone have any ideas? TIA.

Comment: Did you unmount it first?

Comment: The new share was mounted successfully, so I must have done but I decided to unmount it again, and it left it in an unknown state:

```d????????? ? ?             ?               ?            ? /mnt/[share]/ ```

umount again and then a remount of the new share has fixed it. Not sure I exactly understand what's happened but that's done it. Thanks @MichaelHampton

Comment: Ah, so you didn't unmount it first. Reboot the computer.

Answer (score 0):

The way you explain this indicates that sometimes your server share becomes unaccessible. You can unmount with force option (as root) and try to mount again when share becomes available again